# How to capture value from div and display it in another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div with id countsLeft that contains a number (`<div id="countsLeft">10000</div>`) obtained from another div as follows:

```
var countsLeft = $('#countsLeft').text();
```

I want to display this number in another div with id finalMessage via jQuery. What I did is:

```
var finalMessage = 'Thank you, there are ' + countsLeft + ' counts left.;
$('#finalMessage').html(finalMessage); // Same result with .text()
```

This code brings me the following message:

```
 Thank you, there are [HtmlDivObject] counts left.
```

How can this message display the actual numbers instead of this object?

Comment: After adding the missing `'` from the end of the message, it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/kRz9S/. I think `countsLeft` is not what you think it is. Is that variable being assigned to anywhere else?

Comment: Thanks, yes it is on the main page as follows: `<div id="countsLeft" style="display: none;">998</div>`. But the code from the JavaScript runs in Partial Pages (ASP.NET MVC4). Maybe that is a problem, but on the other hand, I can just use the other variable (#count) that is used on the same page and obtained in the same way safely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Jason P](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2266713/jason-p) stated the `countsLeft` variable was not what I thought it was since I assigned it in another namespace. Once I placed the code above in the correct function it worked fine.